# why does my jquery code not work on mobile browser

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm using jquery and my code is like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var bottom = $("div#theid").offset();

  if ( bottom.top - $(window).scrollTop() < 650 ) {
  //do something here
  }

});
```

so when scroll down the browser, will do something, this works just fine on desktop browser, but not on mobile browser, **but if I rotate my phone , this code will work, very strange.**
Why this strange thing happen?
Thank you!

Comment: Add few debug lines somewhere, make a div and append text to it or something

Comment: Please explain the "very strange" code attitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you rotate your phone, the `var buttom` variable changes which effects jQuery to function.